# react router link to the next view only if I get the response from the api request

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api, react-router-dom

So I'm using react-router-dom, here when I click of this link it should fire a function with an api request. what I want to do is to not move to next component it is linked to until I get the response from the request I make in this function

```
postFinal = () =>{
    fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: 
    })
}



 <div className="row">
   <Link to={`/itemSelection/Confirmation`} className="btn" onClick={this.postFinal}>DONE</Link>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a case, instead of using link, use a normal div and use `history.push` to navigate to the intended route

```
postFinal = () =>{
    fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: 
    }).then(() => {
        this.props.history.push('/itemSelection/Confirmation')
    })
}



 <div className="row">
   <div className="btn" onClick={this.postFinal}>DONE</Link>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use`withRouter` from `react-router-dom`

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'


class Home extends React.Component{
 postFinal = () =>{
    fetch('', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: 
    }).then(s=>s.json())
      .then(data=>{
        this.props.history.push('/itemSelection/Confirmation') // this will redirect
    })

}
render(){
 <div>
  <p onClick={this.postFinal}>this is your new link</p>
  </div>
 }

}
export default withRouter(Home);
```

witRouter will add history props to your component, which will be used to naivgate on success of your api